How to Analyze a Transformer Problem with Loops Sharing a Wire?
Context
I am currently taking an electrical engineering class which covers ideal transformers.
I don't know if this is standard, but in the context of the class on ideal transformer means that we ignore mutual inductance and the transformer conserves power (no loss of power).
These are the main formulas I was given for ideal transformers:
$$V_2 = NV_1$$
$$I_2 = \frac{I_1}{N}$$
$$N = \frac{n_2}{n_1}$$

For all these equations:

Subscript 2 refers to the secondary side.
Subscript 1 refers to the primary side.
Voltages and currents are RMS values.
(n) refers to the number of turns.


The problem
I had a quiz which required me to solve a problem similar to this one:
"Consider the 8 Ohm resistor shown in the figure below to be the load. Assume Vg = 110 Vrms at a phase of 0 and a variable turns ration n. What value of n results in the maximum power dissipated by the load?"


For those who can't see the image, I'm sorry but I don't know how to describe it.

Attempted Solution
I tried using impedance reflection and the maximum power transfer (MPT) theorem, ZL = ZS* to solve for n.
Since the circuit only contains resistances, I believe I can simplify the MPT equation from ZL = ZS* to R'L = RS.

R'L is the reflected resistance.

This is how I solved for n:
$$Z_L = Z_S^*$$
$$\therefore R_L' = R_S\text{ and }R_L' = \frac{R_L}{n^2}$$
$$\therefore R_S = \frac{R_L}{n^2}$$
$$\therefore n = \sqrt{\frac{R_L}{R_S}}$$
Where:
$$R_S = 3 + 4 = 7 \Omega$$
$$R_L = 8 \Omega$$


$$\therefore n = \sqrt{\frac{8}{7}} \approx 1.069$$
Issue with Simplistic Solution
I need help because I feel like the answer I provided is too simplistic since it doesn't take into account the voltage provided.
Also, since the loops are connected, I don't think I can use impedance reflection.
Any help and guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Edit
After reading comments that provided hints, I attempted to solve the problem once more by following those hints. However, I have comme  accros a new problem.
Here is what I attempted:

This is what the variables represent:

Vg is the voltage source
n is the turn ration
I1 is the current of the left mesh
I2 is the current of the right mesh


Mesh 1 (left loop) equation:
$$V_g - 3I_1 - 4(I_1 + I_2) = 0$$
Mesh 2 (right loop) equation:
$$-4(I_2 + I_1) - 8I_2 = 0$$
$$\therefore 8I_2 = -4(I_2 + I_1)$$
Relation between I1 & I2:
$$I_2 = -\frac{I_1}{n}$$


$$V_g - 3I_1 - 4(I_1 + I_2) = 0$$
$$\therefore V_g - 3I_1 + 8I_2 = 0$$
$$\therefore V_g - 3I_1 - 8\frac{I_1}{n}= 0$$
$$\therefore 8\frac{I_1}{n} = V_g - 3I_1$$
$$\therefore n = \frac{8I_1}{V_g - 3I_1}$$
$$\therefore n = \frac{8I_1}{110 - 3I_1}$$
This is as far as I could go. I am unsure how to solve for I1, and I don't see how this allows me to solve for the turn ratio n that will maximize the power dissipated by the load.
Thanks again for all your help.

Welcome to Phys SE - first (and really only note): not everyone can see images because it's browser/time dependent. It would be great if you could include only the image part of what you added and then type out the rest from the screenshot so that everyone/search engines can read it.

hint: (1) assign currents to each resistor, (2) use Kirchhoff's equations with the proper application of the transformer equations, (3) calculate the currents as function of $V_g$, (4) calculate power as function of $n.$

Have you learned mesh analysis?

@ThePhoton I have learned mesh analysis, but I am unsure how to apply it for this problem.

@hyportnex I am unsure how to apply Kirchhoff's equations in this context. The transformer's connections is confusing me.

hint: an "ideal transformer" is a 2-port, 4-terminal, device defined by the following equations $V_2=nV_1$ and $I_2=-\frac{1}{n}I_1$ (here the sign is such that both currents are pointing inwards). In your drawing one of the terminal pairs of each port is connected to the other one right above the $4\Omega$ resistor.

@hyportnex I'm sorry, but I don't see how the definition of an ideal transformer helps me use Kirchhoff's equations.

+1 for nicely formatted question for a change from the usual messes. You have two Kirchoff loops, one with Vg, 3ohm and 4ohm, and the other loop with 4ohm and 8ohm. You also have the current junction rule. You should be able to solve this question as it is.
